# Why DAC class is not saved in Acumatica?

Tags: erp, acumatica

Let's say I have following code:

```
DacClass cl = new DacClass();
//init fields of DacClass()
this.Persist();
```

but when I run this code in any graph, I'm getting different errors. Why?

Comment: Ivan, which errors you receive?

Comment: As usually I get error DAC item already exists, or some key error messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create DAC item in db in current graph. As mentioned in T200 manual you should create instance of graph and in created instance to call method persist. Another option is to use method PXDataBase.Insert. The first option is preferable for case if you need  insertion with graph logic. The second option is preferable for cases if you need perfomance.

Comment: I wrote small note: http://blog.zaletskyy.com/yuriy-zaletskyy-s-blog/save-dac-class-in-acumatica-to-db